# Java GUI, trying to position radio buttons and check boxes

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, radio-button, gridbaglayout

So I'm trying to create a series of radio buttons and check boxes that are displayed as follows:

```
          Radio Button
Check Box
          Radio Button
Check Box
          Radio Button
```

However, I'm still in the learning process for java and I was wondering if anyone could solve this problem. At the moment the buttons and boxes are being displayed in the correct location, however the first radio button ("Times") is not being displayed for some reason. If you could perhaps describe the reason and a possible solution that'd be great.

Thanks

Updated Code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Question2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame("Font Chooser");
        f.init();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    void init() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbLayout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(cb, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(cb);
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbLayout.setConstraints(cb, gbc);
        cb = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        mainPanel.add(cb);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton("Times");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(rb, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(rb, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbLayout.setConstraints(rb, gbc);
        rb = new JRadioButton("Helvatica");
        mainPanel.add(rb, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbLayout.setConstraints(rb, gbc);
        rb = new JRadioButton("Courier");
        mainPanel.add(rb, gbc);


        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current output of your code? Are you getting anything close to what you want?

Comment: Currently the 'Helvatica' and 'Times' radio buttons are being output directly on top of eachother. The Check boxes are ok, it's just the radio buttons which are messing up.

Comment: Are you looking to display them in staggered columns, or just two parallel columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem, you are saying each height is 3 high, but really each cell is 1.

```
cRadioButton.gridheight = 3; // change this to 1
```

Here's the full source, and I did make some of the suggested changes from the other answer because at some point you will want to do something different (different action listener implementation for each type of button).

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyFrame1 extends JFrame {
    MyFrame1(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    void init() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbLayout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JCheckBox italic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(italic, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(italic);

        JCheckBox bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbLayout.setConstraints(bold, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(bold);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JRadioButton times = new JRadioButton("Times");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(times, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(times, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JRadioButton helv = new JRadioButton("Helvatica");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(helv, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(helv, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 4;
        JRadioButton courier = new JRadioButton("Courier");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(courier, gbc);
        mainPanel.add(courier, gbc);


        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame1 f = new MyFrame1("Font Chooser");
        f.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem I've got now is that all of the radio buttons are in the same location.
New code for the radio buttons:

Comment: Okay, part of the problem is you are using two different panels - the main panel holds the checkboxes and then you added another panel, newpanel, to hold the radio buttons.  Each panel will be laid out separately.  What I found to be the easiest approach, at least for me, is to draw on paper the layout you want, then draw yourself a grid of rows and columns on top of that.  Using your example column one is the checkboxes and column 2 are radiobuttons.  (0,0) is blank, (0,1) is 1st rb, then (1, 0) is 1st checkbox, (1,1) blank. And so on.  Only use 1 panel - 5 rows, 2 cols.

Comment: Cheers, I tried using your above code, but the radio buttons and check boxes weren't appearing in the correct location. I've altered my code (see above) so that the buttons and boxes are all part of the same frame, the only issue now is that the "Times" radio button is not appearing.

Comment: I have replaced the solution with updated code.  Again, I modified some of it but it works.  I was getting my x and y cordinates mixed up.  The x coordinates go across the row and the y go down the grid.  if this works, please mark the answer as accepted.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you keep reassigning the same object, which may be leading to your overlapping. Instead of

```
JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton("Times");
//...
newPanel.add(rb);
rb = new JRadioButton("Helvatica");
//...
newPanel.add(rb);
//and so on
```

try something like

```
JRadioButton times = new JRadioButton("Times");
JRadioButton helva = new JRadioButton("Helvatica");
//...

newPanel.add(times);
newPanel.add(helva);
```

Comment: So I've done that. It's getting there, however how do I separate the gridy values of the check boxes?

Comment: at present all of the radio buttons have the exact same location.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken elements of your code and have altered my original so that they are all appearing in the same frame, the only issue (as now detailed above) is that the ("times") button is not appearing at all.

Comment: You are still using the same `GridBagConstraints` object "cRadioButton" over and over. Do the same thing for the constraint objects.